# using resultset for updating table

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to update a column of a table from the continuous of another column in the same table after having treated.

I used Java to do the treatment and I only managed to perform this task for the first line of my table.

I do not know why I am unable to browse the "result set". How can I fix this?

```
String Sql = "Select Update_Action,id_incident from incident where Status like'Closed'";
con = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_rapport","root","");
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(Sql);

//treatement
int i = 1;
while(rs.absolute(i))
{
    str = rs.getString(1);
    nom = "";
    while(!"".equals(str))
    {
        int debut = str.indexOf('(') + 1;
        int fin = str.indexOf(')', debut);
        nom += " " + str.substring(debut, fin);
        str = str.substring(fin + 1, str.length()); 
        nom += ", ";

        //updating my table      
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_rapport", "root", "");
        String query = "update incident set intervenants = ? where id_incident=?";

        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, nom);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, rs.getString(2));
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    //for pointing on the next row of "resultset"
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is your SQL query return any result set?

Comment: yes mySQL querry return a result

Comment: why you are connecting your database again in while loop?

Comment: check with rs.next()

Comment: thank you for your answers. before using rs.absolute (), I used rs.next () but nothing the same problem.